# Is there any webpack plugin can resolve static source in html file?

Tags: webpack, frontend

For example, html contain following content

```
<div class="logo-wrap">
    <!-- /dev is developing directory -->
    <img src="/dev/logo.png">
</div>
```

After resolving. It becomes

```
<div class="logo-wrap">
    <!-- /static is deploying directory and a3z51b2l is file's hash -->
    <!-- meanwhile, it moves logo.png from /dev directory to /static directory -->
    <img src="/static/logo.a3z51b2l.png">
</div>
```

Is there any plugin can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in static HTML files you can use the [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin). By default it uses EJS syntax, so in your html file you can do:

```
<img src="<%= require('./local/path/to/img.png') %>" />
```

And webpack will build a static HTML file with the correct path.